# How to remove user from Ubuntu?

Tags: adduser

I added group using the command in terminal as,

```
$ sudo addgroup XXX
```

And I add user under that group,

```
$ sudo adduser --ingroup XXX YYY
```

Now, I need to remove the same group as well as user(s), how to do?

Comment: `deluser <username> <groupname>` and `deluser --group <group name>`

Comment: BUt it shows `You may not remove the user from their primary group.` error for me.

Comment: I think so you use the same name for both user and group.. is it ?

Comment: NO, i put the group name as `ram` and username as `ravi`

Comment: it's work for me again.. I am posting in answer.. please take a look and tell me...

Comment: Wait I will do that.

Comment: @Avinash Raj post it after you got... I will accept..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to run `sudo deluser <username> <groupname>` to delete a user from it's corresponding group. And run this `sudo deluser --group <group name>` command to delete a group.

Comment: `sudo deluser <username> <groupname>` doesn't delete the user, but rather only removes it from `<groupname>`. This, indeed, cannot happen if `<groupname>` is the primary group of `<username>` (e.g., when `<username>` was created with `adduser <username>`). Instead, `sudo deluser <username>` will delete the user completely (naturally removing it from all groups), and also delete the group `<groupname>` if `<username>` was its only member. Otherwise, `sudo deluser --group <group name>` will indeed be needed to delete the group as well.